# Place Named Template into matching folder from an Index

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have the below code to create multiple templates and rename them according to excel tab "Name Index". All names are shown in A1:A100 but what can I add to tell it to also place them into their matching folder name in B1:100 (same tab).

```vb
Public Sub SaveTemplate()
Const strSavePath As String = "C:\\My Documents"
Const strTemplatePath As String = "C:\\My Documents\\template.xls"

Dim rngNames As Excel.Range
Dim rng As Excel.Range
Dim wkbTemplate As Excel.Workbook

Set rngNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Name Index").Range("A1:A100").Values

Set wkbTemplate = Application.Workbooks.Open(strTemplatePath)

For Each rng In rngNames.Cells
wkbTemplate.SaveAs strSavePath & rng.Value
Next rng

wkbTemplate.Close SaveChanges:=False
End Sub
```

```
Public Sub SaveTemplate()
Const strSavePath As String = "C:\\My Documents"
Const strTemplatePath As String = "C:\\My Documents\\template.xls"

    Dim rngNames As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rngNames = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("File Names").Range("A1:A200")
    
    With Application.Workbooks.Open(strTemplatePath)
        For Each rng In rngNames.Cells
            'include folder name from Col B
            .SaveAs strSavePath & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & "\" & rng.Value
        Next rng
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With

End Sub
```

I have tried this code above, but seems to only place the folder name in the title of the newly saved file.

Comment: There's no need to escape a backslash in a VBA string.

Comment: `.SaveAs strSavePath & "\" & rng.Offset(0, 1).Value & "\" & rng.Value` unless values in ColB have a leading backslash.

Comment: Thanks for input. I'm completely new to VBA.

I am not sure what you mean by "\" or if I should be referencing something in my in "File Names" tab.

Comment: \ is the path separator in Windows - so you want ` C:\My Documents\subfolder\file.xls` not `C:\My Documentssubfolder\file.xls`

Comment: It works now. The folders it was looking for were not present resulting in the error. After adding and rerunning, each one was placed in the appropriate folder. Much appreciation!